# ElasticSearch match word "new" anytime when it's not a part of "new york"

Tags: elasticsearch

I have three documents with a single `text` field. Here's their contents:

```
1) {"text": "I want to match docs with a word New"}
2) {"text": "But I don't want to match docs with a phrase New York"}
3) {"text": "However I still want to match docs with a word New which has a phrase New York"}
4) {"text": "For example let's say there's a New restaraunt in New York and I want this doc to be matched."}
```

Is there any way I can match all the docs except 2nd one? Ideally I'd like to use [simple query strings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html) or [query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html), but any other solution will do. I tried to tinker with proximity queries and shignles but failed. I managed to achieve this by using full text regexp match but I don't want to go down this road just yet. Query `-"new york" new` won't match documents 3 and 4. I don't need these two words exactly, the idea of how one can do it is what matters here. Generally I'd like to be able to match any word `A` that isn't prepended/followed by word `B` within some small word distance `N`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your text field is a text datatype or keyword datatype?

Comment: @Lupanoide it's text

Comment: Can you please post the regex query you have tried?

Answer (score 2):

Kind of a hack for this simple problem, but you can try synonym replacement New York, newyork => NY during indexing

Comment: Well it's a good idea but I possibly have more examples like this and I will have to replace a lot of these tokens to make it work. Maybe it's worth the effort.